# Adding a column with awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk, command, addition

I want to add a new column at the beggining of every row. Command used:

> tree -afispugD --inodes

I want to put a new column which will be the name of the file.

Example:

```
119801433 -rwxr--r-- u1915811 alum          1252 Apr  1 21:06  ./file
119802284 -rw-r--r-- u1915811 alum          1255 Mar 20 10:25  ./text.txt
119865862 drwxr-xr-x u1915811 alum          4096 Feb 27 10:20  ./S3/folder2
```

To this:

```
file       119801433 -rwxr--r-- u1915811 alum          1252 Apr  1 21:06  ./file
text.txt   119802284 -rw-r--r-- u1915811 alum          1255 Mar 20 10:25  ./text.txt
folder2    119865862 drwxr-xr-x u1915811 alum          4096 Feb 27 10:20  ./S3/folder2
```

PS: I have to do it because `tree` command doesn't show names :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is:

```
$ awk -F'/' '{print $NF,$0}' file
file 119801433 -rwxr--r-- u1915811 alum          1252 Apr  1 21:06  ./file
text.txt 119802284 -rw-r--r-- u1915811 alum          1255 Mar 20 10:25  ./text.txt
folder2 119865862 drwxr-xr-x u1915811 alum          4096 Feb 27 10:20  ./S3/folder2
```

or if you want to use some specific spacing in the output use printf instead of print:

```
$ awk -F'/' '{printf "%-10s%s\n",$NF,$0}' file
file      119801433 -rwxr--r-- u1915811 alum          1252 Apr  1 21:06  ./file
text.txt  119802284 -rw-r--r-- u1915811 alum          1255 Mar 20 10:25  ./text.txt
folder2   119865862 drwxr-xr-x u1915811 alum          4096 Feb 27 10:20  ./S3/folder2
```

or, since this is a simple substitution on a single line, you could use sed instead of awk:

```
$ sed 's/\(.*\/\(.*\)\)/\2 \1/' file
file 119801433 -rwxr--r-- u1915811 alum          1252 Apr  1 21:06  ./file
text.txt 119802284 -rw-r--r-- u1915811 alum          1255 Mar 20 10:25  ./text.txt
folder2 119865862 drwxr-xr-x u1915811 alum          4096 Feb 27 10:20  ./S3/folder2
```

Answer (score 0):

This one will also work, if file has whitespaces in its name or if it's a symbolic link

```
tree -afispugD --inodes | awk '{FS="./"; ORS=""; printf("%-60s%s\n",$NF,$0)}'
```

Comment: You know you are setting the values of `FS` and `ORS` on every line in the file!? You should instead do `awk '{printf("%-60s%s\n",$NF,$0)}' FS="./" ORS=""`

Comment: I searched for it and found that doing this in BEGIN block is better, because it's executed once, before the first input record has been read. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Yes you can also set the values in the `BEGIN` block but for a one liner just set the values after script

Comment: Okay, I didn't know about it! Thanks once again :)

Answer (score 0):

Until there are spaces in the filenames, this should work:

```
tree -afispugD --inodes | awk '{printf("-30s%s\n",$NF,$0}'
```